# Clipper ainda existe?

Tags: dbase, clipper

Clipper foi uma linguagem muita usada nos anos 80 e até boa parte dos anos 90. Especialmente em alguns países como o Brasil. De fato muitos sistemas administrativos ainda usados hoje foram feitos nele. Mas ainda é possível desenvolver softwares modernos usando ele?

Comment: Gostaria que aparecem programadores que usam estas tecnologias aqui.

Comment: Só pra constar, quando da abertura do SOpt, convidei o pessoal da lista do Harbour, numa mensagem direcionada a quem se comunica em português, a participar. Quem sabe movimentando o assunto eles aparecem por aqui ;) e +1 por tocar no assunto. Eu me surpreendo como tem brasileiro compilando coisa em Clipper ainda.

Comment: Será o ramalho(aquele dos livros) aparece para responder? sempre que alguem fala de clipper é citado os livros dele.

Comment: Eu jamais falaria daqueles livros ruins. Eu aprendi programar de verdade, não tive meu cérebro retalhado por aqueles livros :D

Comment: Eu nunca vi, ouvi falar tinha uns professores que trabalharam com clipper, e falam bem do livro cara. haha

Comment: Eu pessoalmente gostaria de ver tópicos assim falando sobre outras grandes linguagens do passado, como Pascal, Fortran e Cobol[Sendo que essas duas últimas ainda são muito utilizadas, mas para os programadores mais novos não são muito bem vistas]

Comment: As vezes acho que nasci no período Paleozóico, pois além do Clipper trabalhei com Turbo Pascal, PL1 (com SQL), Pick e Zim. E interessante é que no interior ainda vejo sistema rodando em Clipper.

Comment: Isso aqui vai virar ponto de encontro de dinossauros :)

Comment: @perdeu Há uns cinco anos atrás fui convidado a ajudar na migração do sistema de um cartório que fiz em Clipper. Estava funcionando perfeitinho e atendendo mais ou menos bem, mesmo tantos anos depois (nem imaginava que ainda usavam). O Ramalho praticamente foi meu pair-programmer através dos seus livros e guia de bolso. Talvez eu o procure pra agradecer (já que tocamos no assunto).

Comment: Tive um professor na faculdade que o mesmo ainda utiliza clipper até hoje, ele diz que ele faz em clipper o que muito programador não faz em Java, C++, eu sei que ele ganha uma grana boa ainda, ele tem muito software alugado.

Comment: @JoãoNeto se ele ainda usa o Clipper mesmo e não o Harbour, fala pra ele dar um pulinho aqui para se atualizar um pouco sem perder todo investimento que ele fez na tecnologia.

Comment: @bigown irei falar pra ele!

Comment: @JoãoNeto inclusive ele vai poder aproveitar boa parte do código (ou quem sabe todo o código) sem modificações, e recompilar em 32 ou 64 bits, e para uma série de plataformas diferentes se quiser. E o que tiver que modificar, é coisa mínima pra aproveitar recursos novos da própria evolução da plataforma.

Comment: Olá, eu programa em clipper até hoje, tenho que dar manutenção em um sistema monstruoso, +- 45 terminais em rede....funciona perfeitamente !

Comment: Alguns bancos ainda utilizam o mesmo, em Porto Alegre há algumas vagas em aberto.

Comment: Usei o clipper, por um bom tempo, uma linguagem fácil e muito legal para a época do DOS. Ainda tenho programas feito em clipper, foi uma época memoravel.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Destino fatal

O [Clipper](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), aquele produto criado pela Nantucket e comprado pela Computer Associates, foi descontinuado em desenvolvimento por volta de 1996. Ele ainda foi comercializado por muito tempo e até pouco tempo ainda era possível comprá-lo por um terceiro que fez um acordo com a CA.

O Clipper teve seu destino fatal quando a CA desenvolveu o [CA-Visual Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Objects) que era o Clipper mais moderno, orientado a objeto, um pouco mais baixo nível e com um IDE completo. O produto foi mal desenvolvido apesar de algumas ideias muito interessantes e foi um completo fracasso. Parte do problema é que os programadores Clipper não conseguiram entender algumas diferenças da nova linguagem que era parecida com a antiga mas não completamente compatível (o que também contribuiu para o fracasso).

Aí eles não tinham um produto novo interessante e o antigo estava abandonado. Eles não acreditavam que dava para melhorar o antigo e que ainda tinha gente interessada nele. Ajudava o fato do produto não fazer muito sucesso em mercados importantes.

Mas o produto era bom, tinha inovações interessantes e fazia algumas coisas que só foram encontradas em linguagens de sucesso muitos anos depois.

Surgiram alguns clones da linguagem que já era um clone da linguagem do banco de dados simplificado dBase.

## Surge uma esperança

O grande sucesso, se é que podemos chamar assim, se deu com o [Harbour](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(compilador)), uma versão *open source* compatível com o Clipper. Desenvolvido de 1999.

Além de dar total liberdade para os desenvolvedores por não ter uma empresa e sim uma comunidade por traz dele, ganhou-se uma modernização automática já que se abandonou um compilador C 16 bits criado nos anos 80 por qualquer outro moderno compilador C 32 bits, e mais tarde 64 bits. Rodando virtualmente em qualquer plataforma que possua um compilador C (algumas com um pouco de esforço). De uma certa forma códigos Harbour são transformados em códigos C gerando executáveis sempre.

Além disto extensões à linguagem foram criadas mantendo a compatibilidade com códigos legados e muitas novas bibliotecas foram aos poucos desenvolvidas, tais como GUI ([Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) é apenas exemplo), *sockets*, compressão, novas estruturas de dados e algoritmos, criptografia, imagens, Unicode, XML, clientes para diversos bancos de dados relacionais ou de outras tecnologias, melhores acessos ao sistema operacional, melhores formas de acessar seus sistema próprio de banco de dados (`dbf`), *multi-thread* e muita coisa mais.

A linguagem passou ter extensões que permitem orientação a objeto de forma muito semelhante ao adotado por outras linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, ganhou ponteiros (que na verdade são referências), estruturas de *hash* (que na verdade não são *hashes* de fato, é, o pessoal do Harbour é ruim de dar nome), *for each*, *switch*, melhores literais, carregamento dinâmico de código, compilado ou não, e construções que evitam uso de alguns recursos legados considerados ruins além de mais facilidade de integração com código C.

Algumas melhorias também foram adicionadas ao pré-processador que é absurdamente melhor que que o existente para o C (não é ter um pré-processador que é ruim em C, é ter um ruim).

Além disto o compilador melhorou algumas checagens e toda a infraestrutura, além da compilação, foi modernizada.

## Conclusão

Não quer dizer que veremos novos programadores usando uma linguagem que não fica devendo quase nada às linguagens mais modernas mas quem tem código legado ou está bem adaptado à tecnologia ainda pode continuar evoluindo seus *softwares* usando algo que surpreenderia programadores de PHP, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, etc.

Eu só não entendo porque ainda existem programadores que ainda continuam usando o Clipper original, às vezes uma versão antiga dos anos 80.

Então apesar de ter gente que ainda usa, não dá mais para usá-lo diretamente (16 bits!!!). O que dá é para usar a versão modernizada. Existe uma forma melhor de usar a mesma tecnologia. Não só o Harbour, existem outras alternativas ao Clipper (não as conheço bem) tais como xHarbour (um *fork* semiabandonado do Harbour), xBasse++, FlagShip, FoxPro (abandonado pela Microsoft), AdvPL (linguagem proprietária usada no ERP Protheus da Totvs).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quem sabe um Clipper.NET? ;)

Comment: Existiu e já morreu: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.clipper.visual-objects/JOmJotsk61E Não fazia sentido existir, como não faz um monte de linguagem que portaram para o .Net.  
E com esse nome só podia dar nisso :)

Comment: Não fazia idéia. Tadinho. =/

Comment: @OnoSendai Ainda existe o [Vulcan.Net](http://www.govulcan.net/portal/) também parece que será abandonado e o novo [X#](https://www.xsharp.info/) (vai dar rolo com esse nome, já mostra o amadorismo dos caras). Novamente não faz sentido a não ser pegar um resto de mercado de incautos.

Comment: muito obrigado por tantos comentários construtivos e formativos. Desenvolvi milhares de linhas de programação com o bom e velho Clipper. Parti para outros diversos trabalhos, porque não fiz adequação ao modelo visual do windows e desconhecia o Harbour e esse Phyton. Fiz tabelas dinâmicas, cruzamento de dezenas de banco de dados, software para livrarias, loja de calçados, escritório, estoque, médicos, Detran, laboratórios, criação de porcos, postos de gasolina, almoxarifado, financeiro, etc. Obrigado pelas dicas e vou verificar o Harbour, Phyton e o Flagship para Linux. Valeu.

Comment: Não entendo como até hoje existam pessoas ainda presas à essas tecnologias, e o pior, ainda por cima proprietárias onde boa parte dos devs usa sem licença, sim a maioria das ferramentas do padrão XBase são proprietárias.
Usar ferramenta pirata depois de existir soluções 100x mais poderosas e de graça.
Existem várias que ao meu ver seriam bem tranquilas para esse público. Python, Ruby, Julia, Node.js, etc. OOP é um problema? Todas essas que citei são multparadigmas. Em python pode-se criar uma aplicação inteira sem criar nenhuma classe e ainda por cima contando com o Qt5 (PySide2)

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva e eu não entendo como algum sem fundamento algum sobre o assunto resolver expor isso publicamente. 100% do que está dito aí é informação falsa, até a parte que não é sobre xBase. Harbour é 100% aberto, não tem nada de pirata, mais rápido, mais simples, mais elegante, permite tudo o que Python e outras linguagens permitem, inclusive Qt5. Não é 100X mais poderosa, mas não conheço nenhuma linguagem que seja 2 ou 3X mais poderosa que outra, então esta afirmação por si só é até ingênua.

Comment: Dependendo do critério Harbour é mais poderosa que todas as citadas, claro que em algum critério não. E eu conehço bem quase todas, só Julia que eu conheço superficialmente, mas tem bem menos adeptos que xBase. Mas claro, cada um pode gostar e usar o que quiser. E pode até falar sobre o que não conhece. Alias, o comentário é cheio de ranso.

Comment: @Maniero, cuidado com juízos de valor sobre as pessoas sem as conhecer, trabalhei com  Clipper Summer 87 por vários anos, clipper foi minha primeira linguagem, por tanto tenho sim alguma propriedade para dizer alguma coisa. A comparação que fiz foi com clipper, não com harbour, apesar de que ainda vejo harbour muito atrás das que citei, é quase inviável para coisas como IA, Data Science, CV, etc. Web, apesar de até ser possível ninguém em sã consciência arrisca. Já algumas que citei são ideais para isso e mais um pouco.

Comment: @Maniero, Sobre ser ou não free, eu me referi de forma mais genérica, ferramentas citadas como Vulcan.net, VO, Xbase++, etc, são proprietárias, até o próprio clipper 16bits continua a ser proprietário, e limitadas pois se resumem ao desenvolvimento desktop.
Mas eu não quero e não vou transformar isso em um debate, por tanto sinta-se a vontade para fazer o juízo de valor que quiser. Feliz 2019.

Answer (score 7):

Nos anos 90 fiz algumas aplicações em DBaseIII-Plus, Dbase IV e Clipper, preferindo Clipper ao(s) DBase(s). Mas com o aparecimento do Microsoft Windows e o Clipper correndo somente em ambiente DOS, optei pelo FoxPro, mas não gostei e abandonei o Clipper.

Entretanto há três anos descobri o Harbour e gostei da forma como está estruturado e dos seus potenciais, incluindo a portabilidade das aplicações para ambientes *NIX (BSD, Mac, Linux, etc.) além dos tradicionais sistemas operativos da Microsoft, ligações a bases de dados relacionais além dos tradicionais arquivos DBF, criação e utilização de GUI's, etc..

Após ter iniciado o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação de gestão para uma associação, logo optei passar do Harbour para Python, por vários motivos:

1. O desenvolvimento em Harbour estava a ser mais moroso que se fosse efectuado em Python;
2. Comecei a notar que iria ser mais difícil manter o código em Harbour que em Python;
3. Apesar do Harbour estar já estável, havia ainda algumas incertezas no rumo que o Harbour iria tomar;
4. A comunidade Python é maior e oferece mais possibilidades de apoio que a comunidade Harbour.

Até hoje não me arrependo da escolha que fiz.

De salientar que o Harbour é "open source" enquanto que o xHarbour é proprietário.

Comment: Acho sempre interessante ter mais uma resposta do assunto. Só faço questão de salientar que 1 e 2 são mera experiência pessoal do autor em relação à linguagem, e não refletem um problema do Harbour em si (no meu caso, por exemplo, fazer uma aplicação completa em Harbour demora uma fração do tempo que em Py, e assim poderiamos falar de mil outras linguagens). No mais, um bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português ao @lahan, e guardada a ressalva mencionada, recebeu meu voto positivo pelo resto.

Comment: @Bacco Grato pelas boas-vindas e pelo voto positivo.
Quanto à qualidade da resposta, a verdade é que a pergunta: "Mas ainda é possível desenvolver softwares modernos usando ele?" pode originar dois tipos de resposta, que são "sim" e "não". Qualquer resposta dada a esta questão será sempre do ponto-de-vista da experiência pessoal de cada um, porque não é solicitada nenhuma questão especificamente técnica sobre o Clipper. Confesso que ainda hesitei em responder, mas senti que eventualmente a resposta poderia ser útil.