# Perl hoje em dia é utilizado?

Tags: perl

Bom, eu vejo pouca coisa sobre Perl e não conheço muito a linguagem, ela ainda é utilizada hoje em dia e pode substituir alguma outra linguagem como PHP ou Ruby? Não sei exatamente o que Perl faz mas como vejo pouca coisa sobre, e me pareceu interessante, gostaria de saber se tem algum motivo pelo qual não é muito falado se não é mais utilizado ou se simplesmente não vale a pena.

Comment: A sintaxe pode não ser muito clara e também existem variantes você pode iterar um array das seguintes formas: `foreach(1..3) {print $_}`
e `foreach $a (@list){ print "value of a: $a\n";}`. Perl é usado para manipulação de texto alguns 'softwares' que utilizam ele são [pgbadger](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger) e o mrtg. Detalhe a maioria das distribuições linux vem com ele já instalado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim, é bastante usado. Mas não tanto quanto foi no passado. Parte devido ao fato da linguagem ser um pouco ilegível, como já ficou lendário, parte porque a linguagem não evoluiu bem, até mesmo demorando quase décadas para sair uma [versão *major* nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_6) que era bem incompatível com a versão anterior, fruto de um projeto ambicioso demais que nunca deu certo e de várias decisões erradas, e parte ainda porque ela ainda ficou no nicho de *script* que tem menos apelo hoje que antes, e finalmente parte porque outras linguagens foram surgindo com alternativas melhores.

Ainda tem um ou outro maluco que começa nela. Mas o grosso do uso é de quem já estava acostumado com ela. Alguns a adotam porque pegam algum software de código aberto escrito nela e prossegue desenvolvendo a usando. Tem alguns softwares para web muitos bons escritos com Perl. Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa pode ser usada para quase tudo, até mesmo GUI.

Não gosto muito desses sites que medem popularidade de linguagens mas todos mostram que a linguagem ainda tem apelo:

- TOP 10 no [The Transparent Language Popularity Index](http://lang-index.sourceforge.net/) (um pouco desatualizado, mas bem confiável)
- TOP 20 no [*survey* do Stack Overflow em 2017](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017)
- TOP 20 no [PYPL PopularitY of Programming Language](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html)
- TOP 20 do [The 2016 Top Programming Languages](http://spectrum.ieee.org/static/interactive-the-top-programming-languages-2016)
- TOP 15 do [The RedMonk Programming Language Rankings: June 2017](https://redmonk.com/sogrady/2017/06/08/language-rankings-6-17/)
- Beliscando o TOP 10 do [TIOBE Index for July 2017](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)

Um caso que pode ser bem elucidativo é a [tendência de uso do GitHub](http://githut.info/). Não gosto de nenhum critério porque sempre esconde utilizações que não aparecem publicamente. Tenho certeza que as pessoas usam COBOL mais do que imaginam, só que ninguém publica nada sobre ele, a consulta é feita na documentação oficial e não fica espalhado pela internet gerando *hype*, é tudo projeto interno, não tem porque lançar livros, não se troca de emprego fácil nessa área. Mas se quer ver em projetos de código Perl ainda consegue ser TOP 15 em repositórios ativos e próximo disto em *pushes*. Mas cai bem em *forks*, *issues* e *watchers*.

Uma das linguagens mais usadas no Brasil é a [xBase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101). Que é uma guarda-chuva para vários dialetos de uma linguagem. E muita gente não sabe disso. Então essas estatísticas só mostram o que conseguem enxergar. O Brasil é um mercado diferente. Por exemplo, Python parece popular no mundo, mas há até uma piada que programador Python está sempre desempregado, o que é um óbvio exagero... ele sempre sabe outra linguagem para empregá-lo :) Ainda que isso mudou depois que eu escrevi esse texto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).