# Existe alguma linguagem de programação em português? Se sim, em que são aplicadas?

Tags: característica-linguagem, semântica

Como estamos acostumados, "todas" as linguagens de programação (ou quase todas, não sei) seguem o padrão americano, tanto no idioma inglês (`for`, `while`, `if`, `class`, `date`) quanto no formato de data/tempo e de moeda (ex. de data: yyyy/mm/dd).

Existe (ou existem) alguma linguagem de programação cuja semântica e formatos sejam em português? Quais são essas linguagens e em que são aplicáveis e úteis no desenvolvimento de software ou em aplicações web?

Comment: Tinha uma que era para coletor de dados muito interessante inclusive.

Comment: Vai de Prisma, chega a ser até intuitiva visto que as palavras são da nossa língua mãe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nenhuma de uso real. Existe o tal do Portugol que fizeram alguns interpretadores ([Portugol IDE](http://www.dei.estt.ipt.pt/portugol/), [VisualG](http://www.apoioinformatica.inf.br/produtos/visualg), [Portugol Studio](http://lite.acad.univali.br/portugol/)), mas é só para aprendizado. Tem uma versão funcional chamada [Potigol](https://potigol.github.io/).

Tem uma [linguagem muti língua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboMind), entre elas o português.

Já existiu um clone do [dBase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) chamado Dialog que tinha todos os comandos em português na época da maluquice da Lei de Informática que criou enormes distorções e atrasos para o país.

Em tese pode-se pegar qualquer linguagem que tenha um implementação *open source* e modificar para aceitar comandos em português. É muito fácil. Foi mais ou menos o que fizeram com [Prisma](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/).

Note que formatos não costumam fazer parte da linguagem e sim da biblioteca e todas que se prezem lidam com formatos de todos os países.

Semântica (significado) independe da sintaxe (ortografia e gramática) então isto não faz sentido.

Deve existir outras, mas não tem repercussão mínima alguma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Rs.. eu me referi "semântica" ao conjunto de palavras que fazem parte da linguagem (if, else, date, for, class etc). Qual seria a nomenclatura correta pra isso?

Comment: Isto é sintaxe.

Comment: Verdade. Corrigi na pergunta. Segundo o [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sem%C3%A2ntica): "_A semântica contrapõe-se com frequência à sintaxe, caso em que a primeira se ocupa do que algo significa, enquanto a segunda se debruça sobre as estruturas ou padrões formais do modo como esse algo é expresso_".

Comment: @Maniero De uma olhada em https://github.com/DesignLiquido/delegua é um dos projetos que sou mantenedor.

Comment: @SamuelRenanGonçalvesVaz legal, eu tinha visto no Tabnews.

Answer (score 5):

Há o projeto 'prisma' que é uma modificação dos fontes Lua 5.2. Uma linguagem interpretada com 'statements' em português.

Possui acesso a banco de dados SQLite3 e MySQL, interface gráfica bem básica; cgi, md5, sha1, sha256, pdf, entre outras coisas;

Segue o link do site para mais informações:

http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/blog

fórum: http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/prisma_forum/

Alguns exemplos de código:

```
    imprima"olá mundo\n";

    para i = 1, 10 inicio
      imprima(i);
    fim

    local cont=0;
    enquanto cont <= 10 inicio
      imprima(cont);
      cont = cont + 1;
    fim
```

Comment: Eu uso Prisma há pelo menos 1 ano e no quesito aprendizado, posso garantir que pra quem é lusófono não terá qualquer dificuldade de aprender inclusive quem não tem noção de programação. Está precisando de apoio de mais programadores vamos ajudar aí galera.

Answer (score 1):

Existe sim! Uma linguagem de programação nova totalmente em português chamada Br.ino. Ela é focada no uso do arduino e parece que pode ser expandida para outras línguas tambem. Link dela: http://brino.cc

Answer (score 0):

Existe a [Linguagem Potigol](http://potigol.github.io) que é uma linguagem multiparadigma (imperativa, funcional e OO) moderna em português para ensinar programação. A sua sintaxe lembra as linguagens de script como Ruby e Python mas a semântica é baseada em linguagens de tipagem estática. Potigol é usada também para criar [jogos gráficos 2D](https://ifrn.github.io/jerimum).

Veja o exemplo de um programa que calcula a área e o perímetro de um quadrado:

```
tipo Quadrado
  lado: Real
  area() = lado * lado
  perimetro() = 4 * lado
fim

escreva "Qual o tamanho do lado?"
a = leia_real
q1 = Quadrado(a)
escreva "Área = {q1.area}"
escreva "Perímetro = {q1.perimetro}"
```

Comment: "Potigol" tem alguma coisa a ver com "Potiguar"? Foi a primeira coisa que me veio à cabeça ao ler esse nome

Comment: Sim. A linguagem foi desenvolvida no IFRN em Natal. O nome era uma brincadeira mas acabou ficando.