# Significado de .CH nas linguagens Clipper e ADVPL?

Tags: header, advpl, clipper

Quando utilizamos uma linguagem como Clipper ou ADVPL, normalmente utilizamos as bibliotecas (*includes*) .CH, todavia não sei o que significa.

Na linguagem C, esses arquivos de cabeçalho tem o sufixo .H, que significa *Header File*.

Acredito que deva ser *Custom Header File* ou *Clipper Header File*, porém ainda não tenho certeza.

Assim sendo, qual o real significado do acrônimo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está correto.

Conhece o `.h` do C, certo? Ou seja, o arquivo de cabeçalho com predefinições do que será útil para o código em si da linguagem? É a mesma coisa só que é da ADVPL.

Esse `C` é de Clipper, a linguagem que deu origem à ADVPL, portanto não é uma criação da ADVPL em si e sim legado do Clipper. Foi adotado isso justamente para não confundir com o `.h` do C, algo que os desenvolvedores do Clipper trabalhavam fortemente e mesmo outros usuários do Clipper chegavam usar. A gente fazia muita coisa em C para usar com o Clipper.

De fato algumas pessoas na Totvs preferem adotar como *Custom* para se afastar do Clipper, mas nem é um significado correto para o que ele é de fato.

Não achei nada que documente oficialmente, mas lembro disto no Clipper. Não importa muito o que o `C` no acrônimo significa e sim para o que o arquivo serve.

Embora nada impeça de colocar qualquer coisa no `.CH` em geral não se coloca nada do que é considerado a linguagem em si. Na verdade em [Clipper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101)/Harbour/ADVPL isso é até um pouco diferente do C. Em C essas coisas não fazem parte da linguagem e o pré-processador é bem "burro", ele só troca textos sem maiores análises.

Nessas linguagens chamadas xBase o pré-processador é muito mais poderoso, ele entende melhor o código e faz bem mais que só trocar texto. Então podemos até considerar como parte da linguagem.

Não sei se mudou alguma coisa, mas há um tempo o pré-processador da ADVPL era um pouco inferior ao do Clipper em alguns pontos específicos. O do Harbour é extremamente mais poderoso e dá para fazer algumas coisas incríveis, dá até para abusar bastante. Embora a maioria só use para o básico mesmo. No Harbour vira um recurso de metaprogramação quase completo.