# A que ponto sintaxes em linguagens de programação tornam-se importantes?

Tags: característica-linguagem, sintaxe, independente-de-linguagem

Eu estou afim de discutir sobre o assunto de quando uma sintaxe de uma linguagem de programação N torna-se importante para a produção de sistemas.

Por exemplo: Uma linguagem com sintaxe simples e fácil de aprender, interfere na escolha de qual linguagem irei construir o sistema que desejo?

Também é possível de um desenvolvedor de sistemas trocar sua linguagem de programação mesmo com o sistema bem evoluído, por motivos de alguma grande urgência? Se sim, que tipo de urgências poderiam ser essas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não fazemos discussões aqui, damos respostas objetivas ou subjetivas fundamentadas pelo menos na experiência da pessoa.

Sou um "estudioso" de linguagens de programação e por muito tempo fui adorador de sintaxes. O tempo me fez ver que só importa de verdade a semântica. A sintaxe tem a função de deixar o trabalho do programador agradável, uma boa sintaxe é uma boa UX para o programador, mas raramente ela influencia no resultado final. Claro algumas sintaxes podem favorecer um código mais correto ou incentivar um código mais performático ou influenciar em outros pontos, mas não é ela sozinha que define isto.

Sabe aquela coisa de que deve usar a melhor ferramenta para o problema? A sintaxe de uma linguagem de programação nunca é um ponto importante nisso, ou até mesmo a linguagem como um todo faz pouca diferença exceto em casos extremos (não vai escrever um sistema operacional em JavaScript ou fazer um *front* web com C, dá mas não é adequado).

Você pode decidir o critério que quiser para decidir que linguagem usar. Ser simples e fácil de aprender são duas coisas distintas, muitos acham que é a mesma coisa. Simples é um termo meio ambíguo, eu imagino que seja fácil de usar. Sempre prefira o fácil de usar porque a maior parte do tempo você **usa** a linguagem, pouco tempo você aprende, então ser fácil de aprender é um característica desejável por ingênuos ou porque a pessoa vai usar aquilo uma vez e jogar fora.

Eu não levo isso a ferro e fogo mas a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você sabe. Se fizer pouca diferença use aquela que você domina (e deve dominar, não só saber). Claro que só porque você sabe PHP não vai fazer um software desktop, ou fazer web o que deveria ser desktop (este último caso é trocar o problema de forma equivocada para a linguagem se encaixar no seu gosto).

Mas facilidade de usar e aprender deve ser 2% a sintaxe e 90% a semântica e 6% outras coisas (números chutados). A sintaxe as pessoas escolhem por gosto.

Por exemplo, PHP está tomando um rumo pela sua evolução e pela forma que as pessoas usam que deveriam trocar de linguagem, PHP está se tornando um Java com sintaxe de PHP, não faz sentido, se quer programar em Java programe em Java. Se não gosta, vai de C#. Se ainda quiser muito a sintaxe de PHP vai de [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101).

Trocar a linguagem no meio do projeto não faz muito sentido por tudo isso que já disse acima. Você deveria dizer que urgência é esta, eu não consigo ver alguma.

Por isso não aconselho se enveredar em linguagens com pouca comunidade, mas mesmo assim não costuma ser trágico. Está aí COBOL, ainda tem muita gente usando [Clipper/Harbour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) de forma moderna, e até mesmo Delphi, que é uma linguagem proprietária e as pessoas estão correndo disto, ainda vive bem.

É muito raro, pra não dizer impossível, mas se precisar mesmo trocar uma linguagem porque algo não foi factível ainda pode fazê-lo só em um ponto específico e manter o que foi desenvolvido. Só espero que isso não sirva de desculpa para adotar microsserviços porque existe como resolver isso de forma mais simples.

Somos, ou deveríamos ser, engenheiros, somos solucionadores de problemas, sempre há uma forma de resolver, algumas melhores, outras piores. E quando não conseguimos resolver chamamos quem consegue. As coisas complexas devem ser resolvidas por seniores mesmo. O júnior pode até tentar mas correrá o risco de fazer pior.

Soluções devem ser dadas observando o caso concreto, não existem respostas mágicas que solucionem tudo, se fosse assim não precisaria de tanto desenvolvedor.

Se preocupe com a semântica da linguagem, com sua filosofia geral e como ela é implementada, e o que pode em alguns casos ser até mais definidor, sua biblioteca padrão e as de terceiros existentes (embora isso hoje já ficou mais linear na maioria dos casos).

Eu gosto de C# porque alia melhor todos esses pontos para quase qualquer tipo de aplicação (até é para qualquer tipo se abrir mão da máxima adequação), e tem sintaxe de bom gosto :). Cada um tem que achar seu jeito e conviver com essa escolha, ou trocar se for necessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: eu sempre obtive essa duvida. Um prof meu uma vez citou a frase "o python reduz a quantidade de codigo a ser trabalhado". Logo imaginei que teria alguma importancia quando vai trabalhar com programação, pois teria algo envolvendo o tempo que você está determinado em solucionar tal problema. Conheço pouco ainda do C# mas pretendo aprender um pouco sobre essa linguagem.

Comment: Uma outra duvida que sempre tive, era do exemplo de uma empresa em minha cidade que minha prima trabalha. Eles estavam utilizando um sistema desenvolvido em delphi. Agora essa empresa esta mudando tudo. Segundo a minha prima, estão utilizando um outro sistema para a gestão da empresa. Ela ainda mesmo me disse "O sistema é em delphi, ja sabe o porque estamos mudando né?".