# Por que existem tantas linguagens de programação?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem

Há várias décadas, as linguagens de programação surgiram para facilitar a vida dos programadores e indiretamente, do público geral também.

No início, tudo era feito com botões que representavam números binários. Então as pessoas perceberam que acabavam sempre apertando os mesmos botões em sequência várias vezes, então vieram os cartões perfurados.

Depois elas perceberam que podiam escrever um programa em um computador que permitisse elas escreverem o código ali, surgindo então as primeiras linguagens de programação, como FORTRAN e LISP.

O tempo foi passando e cada vez mais linguagens foram surgindo como C, COBOL, BASIC, entre outras.

Mas por que cada vez mais linguagens foram surgindo? Mesmo sabendo que as primeiras linguagens eram complicadas, o que justifica o surgimento de novas nos dias de hoje? Atualmente, existem mais de **400 linguagens de programação**, podendo existir até mais **milhares** de linguagens, e na maior parte do mundo, menos de 25% delas são usadas.

Sendo assim, **por que existem tantas linguagens de programação?**

Comment: Existem linguagens de programação mais ou menos indicadas para cada uma das múltiplas classes de problemas a serem resolvidos. Agora você está sendo muito modesta, a última vez que pesquisei existiam mais de 2.500 diferentes linguagens de programação

Comment: Li por cima as respostas, mas não vi comentarem, então vou comentar algo aqui, existem linguagens simplesmente criadas por algum "capricho" pessoal (php eu vejo como um exemplo disto) ou entretenimento (geralmente linguagens "esotéricas"). No caso do PHP, Rasmus a criou para seu uso pessoal e realmente era diferente do que é hoje, na verdade a ideia dele sobre linguagens as vezes era um pouco equivocada, mas não vou criticar, o foco é que a linguagem foi adotada por uma "comunidade" e eles evoluíram ela, ou seja, deixando de ser o que era [...]

Comment: [...] então seu motivo inicial não foi bem resolver algo que outra linguagem não conseguia, foi inicialmente para ser algo pessoal que ele muito bem poderia ter feito com outro interpretador, como era comum na época, talvez o Perl (na época geralmente se usava CGI (porta/protocolo))... Outros possíveis (sobre outras linguagens) motivos provavelmente são o "comercial/marketing", ou seja uma empresa de tecnologia que desenvolve a própria linguagem deve ser algo "incrível" aos olhos do "mundo" (ao menos assim as pessoas esperam)

Comment: Pra celebrar a pergunta, achei curioso porque vi esse vídeo ontem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Og847HVwRSI

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Existem vários motivos:

1. **Evolução natural das linguagens**: da mesma forma que na linguagem humana, onde ela nasceu com simples fonemas e de acordo com a evolução do ser humano e sua migração e separação geográfica, ela foi se adaptando e evoluindo de forma conjunta. As linguagem de programação, como você mesmo mencionou, surgiram das formas mais rudimentares e conforme os programadores e desenvolvedores foram percebendo que coisas poderiam ser feitas de forma melhor, mais intuitiva e portanto mais rápida, foram criando suas próprias linguagens.
2. **Adaptação com o momento histórico**: até o final dos anos 70, por exemplo, reinavam os ***mainframes***, as empresas (grandes) que os possuiam tinham enormes e complexas estruturas de desenvolvimento, envolvendo **analistas de sistemas** (que analisavam a necessidade, criavam fluxogramas - diagramas de blocos), que passavam este material para os **programadores** (que tentavam entender o que o analista queria e codificavam um programa em papel de 80 colunas), os quais passavam este material para os **digitadores** que fariam o digitação do código fonte no sistema operacional do mainframe, etc. Havia **muita gente envolvida para gerar um simples programa** (e muita coisa podia dar errado), desta forma, era necessário uma linguagem de programação que fosse mais *prolixa*, como o **COBOL**, para que tudo ficasse bem detalhado, nada *subentendido*.
   A medida que foram desaparecendo estas mega-estruturas, com o **surgimento do PC** e a figura dos profissionais foram se sintetizando em apenas uma pessoa (que analisa, programa, digita, compila, testa, etc), o paradigma foi mudando e o foco ficou mais na inteligibilidade, objetividade, entre outros.
3. **Novas tecnologias / hardwares**: conforme foram evoluindo as tecnologias (como por exemplo o surgimento da internet, dispositivos móveis, etc), novos tipos de hardware, além de sistemas operacionais diferentes (Windows, Ios, Android, Linux) foi-se percebendo que cada caso tinha uma realidade específica. Algumas empresas criaram sistemas proprietários que não aceitavam linguagens pre-existentes e exigiam novas linguagens a serem usadas. Cada novo modelo de processador criado traz consigo novas regras, novos recursos que antes não haviam sido explorados. Teoricamente você poderia fazer tudo numa linguagem de baixo nível, mas isso levaria anos para se fazer algo que poderia ser reduzido a minutos numa linguagem de alto nível.
4. **Idiossincrasia**: com o passar do tempo e com a experiência, muitos programadores foram percebendo que "isso ou aquilo" em determinada linguagem poderia ser feito bem melhor de outra forma... então muitos se lançaram numa "aventura" de criar algo novo com a finalidade de facilitar e melhorar as dificuldades anteriores. E aí vêm junto as particularidades de cada ser humano que coloca sua forma de pensar e seu estilo pessoal nesta nova linguagem. Veja o exemplo do **Python** que leva consigo uma série de ideias do seu criador, que por sua vez repercutiram positivamente em várias pessoas que abraçaram esta nova forma, que por sua vez transformou-a numa linguagem de sucesso. Mas creia que para cada sucesso, existem milhares de fracassos desconhecidos por aí.
5. **Futuro**: não creio que um dia teremos uma *linguagem universal* como filosoficamente se deseja até para a humanidade. Ao contrário, penso que haverá cada mais **especialização**, ou seja, cada-macaco-no-seu-galho, cada linguagem cumprindo (bem) sua função.

Answer (score 22):

- Um dos motivos é que **existem muitos problemas diferentes**, necessidades que não podem ser supridas por um só modelo de programação. Mas isso envolve o certo grau de falácia, falo mais abaixo. O motivo oficial é este, os demais são secundários. Para isso ser exercido de forma adequada a linguagem precisa ser de um [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) diferente.

  Salvo algo bem pontual linguagens não são melhoradas para atender evolução do hardware, pelo menos não por razões técnicas, já que por razões políticas do fornecedor do hardware pode haver a adoção ou crianção de nova linguagem. Também não existe isso por causa de sistema operacional.

  Em algum ponto podemos dizer que é porque existe pregos e parafusos e por isso precisa de ferramentas diferentes, mas quando o cabo é de plástico ou madeira, ou metal, ou é curvado ou tem outras características é porque tem gente que gosta de jeito diferente, não porque é necessário.
- Um ponto secundário deste é que **linguagens sempre possuem falhas** e uma nova vem para dar uma solução para estas falhas. Muitas dessas falhas são subjetivas, o que permite sempre alguém achar um motivo para fazer algo diferente. Não tem como fazer uma linguagem perfeita, uma característica positiva tende impedir uma outra ou cria um negativa.

  Uma linguagem é difícil de gerenciar a memória? Cria outra que faz isso de forma mais simples. Uma linguagem exige escrever código demais e expressar com oas coisas realmente são? A linguagem não permite escrever códigos muito grandes com facilidade? Uma linguagem é legal mas na forma exatamente construída é ineficiente? Tudo isso pode ser resolvido usando a base do que já existe, ma mudando alguns detalhes que resolvem esse problema.
- Outro motivo é que as pessoas querem ter um certo domínio de mercado ou marcar sua posição na história, então elas acham alguma coisa que pode ser feita de um jeito um pouco diferente mesmo que não seja tão diferente assim. Isto pode acontecer porque **as pessoas tendem a gostar de coisas por causa de pequenos detalhes**.

  Por que existem tantas marcas e variedades de tantos produtos? Pelos motivos que falei acima, então linguagem de programação não é diferente. Por que você precisa de um carro branco e outro azul? Isso não muda nada na vida das pessoas.

  É claro que uma nova linguagem resolve um problema encontrado em outra linguagem, mesmo que este problema não seja tão relevante, mas a maior questão é que as pessoas querem fazer coisas diferentes. Faria sentido ter algumas poucas linguagens muito diferentes, o resto é só briga por espaço. É até uma falácia parcial essa questão de que cada uma atende uma necessidade diferente. Claro que em parte isso é verdade, mas parte é só atender um gosto diferente. Salvo em alguns cenários faz pouca diferença usar uma coisa ou outra.

  Então o motivo real é que as pessoas gostam de cosias diferentes e tem gente que quer suprir isso.
- Por que existem vários tipos de computadores? Ou de carros? Muitos deles não existem de fato mais porque se tornaram obsoletos, eles eram bons na época que foram criados, mas hoje não mais. Com linguagem se dá o mesmo, com a diferença que ela não desgasta com o tempo e ainda pode ser usada.

  Novamente, quem criou algo no passado tenta manter seu produto relevante e faz melhorias. Isto só funciona porque **tem quem goste**.

Em essência todas linguagens de programação conseguem fazer tudo o que é necessário e algumas são ligeiramente melhores em algum ponto específico. Muitas vezes você vê mais diferença na implementação de uma linguagem do que de uma linguagem para outra.

Linguagens são formas de expressão então cada um tem um jeito preferido de fazê-lo. Em alguns casos esse jeito pode ser mais fácil para certos cenários. Não é tão diferente de línguas naturais. Inclusive algumas servem melhor do que outras. Algumas servem melhor para assuntos técnicos outras servem melhor para cenários artísticos.

Já notou uma força muito grande das pessoas tentarem evangelizar sobre o uso de uma determinada linguagem? As pessoas sabem que maior adoção gera maior adoção e isso se faz necessário. A maioria das adoções são feitas pelo marketing, mesmo espontâneo, e não pela característica técnica real. Claro que é raro adoções muito fora de parâmetro, mas também é raro ter alguma coisa que seja muito complicado fazer em linguagens diferentes.

Atualmente existem milhares de linguagens de programação e cada um tem o direito de criar sua própria, o que vai determinar se ela será conhecida é o quanto se consegue divulgá-la e ter aderência de outras pessoas. E milhares são usadas, só varia a quantidade do uso.

Muitas linguagens não são criadas para serem produtos viáveis e sim experimentos ou evoluções de alguma existente.

Muitas vezes eu vi pessoas adotarem uma linguagem não por ela ser diferente mas por ela ter uma biblioteca que as pessoas queriam usar daquele jeito. Inclusive alguns acham que uma mudança na biblioteca cria outra linguagem quando isso não é verdade.

Fato é que existem literalmente infinitas combinações possíveis de se fazer em uma linguagem. Cada um enxerga uma combinação como melhor que outra.

Fica até mais fácil avaliar linguagem contra linguagem sobre isso. Por exemplo, existe um motivo para as pessoas usarem C ou C++ e não é performance como muitos acham, só pessoas ingênuas acham isto. Vou tentar colocar algumas motivações que vemos por aí para dar um visão geral de como as escolhas são feitas. Claro que estou fazendo simplificações.

**C** foi criada para ser um Assembly portável. E ser algo mais fácil de expressar que ALGOL que é uma linguagem fantástica mas muito chata de usar.

**C++** foi inicialmente criada para adicionar classes em C, de dar melhores abstrações sem pagar nada por isso.

**Java** foi criada para ser um C++ melhor (nunca chegou nem perto disso, é pior que C++ em quase tudo que não envolve robustez).

**C#** foi criada para a Microsoft ter uma alternativa ao Java já que ela foi proibida de evoluir o Java. E também para ser o que Java disse que seria, ou seja um C++ melhor, então ela ficou no meio termo entre C++ e Java.

A grande diferença destas linguagens para C++ é o gerenciamento de memória.

**VB.NET** é o VB para o .NET. VB é o BASIC mais adequado ao Windows e que a Microsoft podia controlar a evolução. Tem uma quantidade incomensurável de dialetos BASIC. Esta linguagem surgiu para ser uma alternativa simples ao que existia por aí como FORTRAN ou COBOL.

**F#** existe para ter uma pegada funciona no .NET, baseada inicialmente em OCaml.

**Pascal** deveria ser ALGOL mais pragmática.

**Delphi** seria o Pascal com classes, uma tentativa da Borland de manter seu mercado em torno do Pascal em face das novidades que surgiam.

**Objective C** foi criada por descontentamento de alguns com a forma do C++ lidar com orientação a objetos. Swift foi criada porque Objective C tinha problemas demais e ainda mantinha o legado de C.

**R** foi criada para facilitar estatísticas. É uma das poucas linguagens que impõe uma diferença real que faz sentido existir além de gosto.

**Rust** foi criada porque C++ tem muitas falhas e Java e assemelhados possuem *tracing garbage collector*.

**Go** foi criada para ser C com GC e corrigir alguns erros dessas linguagem, além de permitir melhores abstrações (mas nem tanto em alguns casos), e também pra compilar rápido. Assim como acontece em outras linguagens, o mercado vai para outro lado e os objetivos mudam. Nem sempre o criador consegue manter a linguagem do jeito que ela pensou, as pessoas podem adotá-la, mas ter outras ideias.

**D** foi criada porque C++ era complexa de mais. Não deu tão certo e estão reformulando os objetivos.

**Dart** foi criada porque JS era muito ruim.

**Scala** nasceu para ter uma vertente mais funcional para Java

**Kotlin** surgiu para ter uma alternativa sem os problemas do Java rodando na JVM (tinha outros objetivos inicialmente, mas foram abandonados).

**Eifell** foi criada para demonstrar que é possível fazer herança múltipla e como é o uso de contratos.

**Haskell** surgiu para ensinar Haskell para as pessoas :P :D

Dizem que V foi criada para arrecadar dinheiro de incautos (não sou eu que disse isso :) ).

**JavaScript** surgiu para permitir customizar páginas web com comportamentos, e por isso deveria ser uma linguagem simples e fácil de usar, não para fazer aplicações. Boa parte das escolhas feitas para ela foram por falta de escolha, ou pelo menos falta de tempo para escolher fazer coisas melhores.

**TypeScript** foi criada para colocar tipos e mais organização em JS, permitindo assim aplicações.

**PHP** foi criada para facilitar o trabalho de criar páginas web onde o C que era usado pelo criador era muito complicado.

**Python**, **Ruby**, **Perl** e outras surgiram para serem algo parecido, ou pelo menos para serem capazes de fazer *scripts* de forma mais simples do que C, Pascal ou outra linguagem do tipo, mas mais poderoso que awk, bash e outros *shells*. Ruby queria por OOP em *scripts*, linda ideia.

Python por exemplo tentou dar um ar de linguagem funcional mas com o jeito imperativo que todo mundo está acostumado, que é uma receita para o sucesso, porque linguagens funcionais são simples e bonitas, mas ruins para certos padrões de uso. Daí vem a indentação para definir bloco.

**Groovy** existe para ser uma alternativa dinâmica ao Java.

**Lua** foi criada porque precisavam de um tecnologia brasileira para fazer *scripts* simples e com performance embarcando em outras aplicações.

**Boo** deveria ser um Python melhor rodando no .NET, mas morreu por falta de comunidade e comprometimento do criador, talvez porque C# melhorou boa parte das coisas que Boo trouxe.

**Elixir** deveria ser Erlang dinamicamente tipada entre outras "melhorias".

**dBase** foi criada para suportar um banco de dados simples. [**Clipper**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) foi criada inicialmente como um compilador de dBase, mas depois preciso evoluir para poder criar aplicações completas. **Harbour** foi criada para atender quem ficou órfão de Clipper e acabou tendo uma evolução natural para atender novas demandas. **FoxPro** deveria ser o Clipper de outra empresa para ganhar um pouco dos rios de dinheiro que a Nantucket estava ganhando. Tem outros dialetos criados cada um por interesse de uma empresa.

Essas últimas linguagens costumam abrir mão de eficiência para dar mais facilidade. Algumas menos que outras, um exemplo é Lua que consegue ser fácil e simples sem ser muito ineficiente.

Tem umas linguagens que ninguém sabe porque foi criada porque ela só piora as coisas :) Em geral é só gosto do criador.

Eu acho curioso como algumas linguagens foram criadas com um objetivo claro e foi mudando, hoje é outra coisa e ninguém percebe. Muita gente defendia a linguagem como era e hoje defende o outro jeito indo contra sua argumentação inicial. As pessoas torcem por times, por partidos políticos e por empresas e tecnologias, tudo de uma forma religiosa mas com dogmatismo tendencioso com o discurso do momento. Isso dá espaço para surgir novas linguagens, as pessoas estão esperando um discurso que faça mais sentido para ela.

Algumas linguagens são verdadeiras *frankensteins*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Falou sobre o "marketing" e "mercado" +1

Comment: "Haskell surgiu para ensinar Haskell para as pessoas :P :D" KkKkkKkKkKKkk, rindo até 2030

Answer (score 7):

Dentre os diferentes motivos temos:

- Evolução tecnológica. O que foi inventado ontem pode não servir mais para o hoje. A necessidade de hoje pode ser diferente da necessidade de ontem. Esse é um dos motivos que levou a criação do Java.
- As linguagens existentes podem ser insuficientes ou deficientes para atender-se a determinados requisitos. Foi isso que fez o paradigma orientado a objetos nascer e levar a criação de linguagens que seguem este paradigma.
- Há nichos específicos que requerem linguagens especiais. Um exemplo óbvio disso é SQL. O JavaScript nasceu assim, para ser uma linguagem específica para rodar no navegador. O PHP também nasceu assim. Outro exemplo é a variante de C usada no Arduino ou a variante de C# usada no Unity.
- Pessoas diferentes tem opiniões diferentes sobre detalhes da estrutura das linguagens de programação. Por exemplo, C tem ponteiros e aritmética de ponteiros, mas algumas pessoas consideram isso ruim, e isso foi um dos motivos que fez surgir o Java. Os Basics antigos foram muito atacados por não serem estruturados (era tudo baseado em GOTOs e GOSUBs). Existe uma "guerra dos 100 anos" em curso entre linguagens com tipagem estática e tipagem dinâmica. Uma das inspirações do Python foi a de usar a indentação para aninhar estruturas e considerar que as demais linguagens tinham uma estrutura muito complicada. Tem gente que é mais a favor de funcional, tem gente que prefere OO, tem gente que odeia OO, etc. E muitas outras coisas entram nessa categoria.
- Fornecedores específicos. Existem várias linguagens de programação que são desenvolvidas por um único fornecedor. Daí vem um fornecedor diferente e sugere uma linguagem parecida, mas com algumas diferenças (umas pequenas, outras grandes). Depois vem mais um outro e pega o que havia dos predecessores e faz uma outra coisa similar para os seus produtos... Esse é um dos motivos de terem existido tantas variações de Cobol, Basic e C, por exemplo. Linguagens como D e C# nasceram assim. Em casos mais modernos isso tende a ser mais raro, mas ainda existe, tal como o React.js pode comprovar.

Answer (score 2):

Teve uma palestra muito legal que vi na XConf desse ano do Luciano Ramalho e da Rosi Teixeira da TW que falaram um pouco sobre isso.

A estrutura básica de lógica de programação mudou muito pouco no decorrer dos anos.

Condicionais usam IF, laços usam FOR, While, para comparação usa-se >,< =, ==, && e por ai vai.

O que acontece é que os problemas mudam conforme os anos vão passando, os recursos vão melhorando e existe uma questão de experiência do desenvolvedor, dai os paradigmas vão surgindo. Assim como o tipo de comunicação (TCP/IP, SOAP, REST, Grpc).

Evoluções vão acontecer, linguagem que utilizam melhor os recursos vão surgir e isso é inevitável. Antes tínhamos arquitetura de cliente servidor, veio SOA, Microsserviços, serverless e isso nunca terá fim!

Imagina como seria o desenvolvimento de uma arquitetura serverless em cobol? sem chance.

Novas arquiteturas surgirão pois existem novas necessidades de negócio.

Como o time-to-market deve ser baixo, a experiência do desenvolvedor deve ser boa, pois a entrega deve ser ágil, a curva de aprendizado deve ser baixa.

Eu escuto todo dia gente falando que o Java é verboso demais e o Spring vem pra ajudar.

Hoje com meia dúzia de @ um dev consegue entregar um microsserviço de CRUD.

Enfim, novas linguagens surgem para suportar novas arquiteturas, necessidades de negócio e para atender a experiência do usuário.

Comment: O único motivo de algo"serverless" não funcionar com COBOL é fornecedores de servidores "serverless" não suportarem a tecnologia.

Comment: Ou seja, sem chance!

Answer (score -8):

Cada tipo de linguagem é usada para algo especifico, por exemplo, a linguagem CSS é usada para estilizar layouts, a linguagem HTML5 é usada para desenvolver páginas da internet, algumas linguagens tem vários propósitos, como a C++ ou a Python que pode tanto ser usada para desenvolver uma automação residencial como uma IA, por exemplo.

Cada linguagem de programação tem um propósito diferente, mas a maioria foi desenvolvida para a resolução de problemas.

Comment: CSS e HTML não são linguagens de programação. Me cite uma linguagem que não foi criada para resolução de problemas.

Comment: @Maniero, Whitespace! Ela foi criada para **ser** o problema xD

Comment: @Maniero [BIRL](https://birl-language.github.io/)